# Mail file as well as output

Tags: linux, shell

I have a python script which prints some data and also writes data to a file as well.

I wanted to mail both the stuff from the linux terminal.

I am using the below command.

```
python script.py | mail -s "subject" -a filename.txt example@gmail.com
```

It mails me the output( print one ), but not the file at that time.
Gives an error no such file or directory(because its being created at that time )

The next time I run this it mails me both the stuff, as the file is there.

How Can I accomplish this task ( mail both the stuff ), when I ran the linux command for the first time.

Thanks

Comment: Links of a pipeline run concurrently. That's why it doesn't work. You can do what Jonny Henly says.

Comment: @PSkocik, Good catch. Took a while for me grasp it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pipe the Python script to `mail` instead redirect the output to a temporary file and then `cat` that temporary file piping it to the `mail` command.

For instance:

```
python script.py > temp-file.out
< temp-file.out mail -s "subject" -a filename.txt example@gmail.com
```

Comment: It might be worth doing it as the redirect temp file variation, python script.py >temp-file.out, cat temp-file.out | mail, if it's a lot of output.

Comment: @BenPen good point for that scenario, but OP says the script is only outputting a date and writing the rest to a file.

Comment: @jonny-henly sorry for the typo, its data

Comment: @Sherry in that case BenPen's suggestion should be used, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yeah, it's true, for small <1K bytesish, I guess, it's worth not having to worry about concurrency and locations for temp files.  And if the files are BIG enough and run often enough, you start worrying about temp directories to contain the mess.

Comment: Thank you eveyone for the help

Comment: Though that's the prototypical [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) - you want `mail -options <temp-file.out` instead.